# Phase-oriented allocation in Rust with arenas

Tags: rust

I'm trying to build an application that consumes data from Kafka. Data is being aggregated into 5 minute buckets and I need to "remember" the last 10 buckets and then drop the buckets as they become too old.

For the aggregation purpose, I need to allocate some objects and I would like to use the arena approach so these allocations are fast. I want to bind each bucket to a specific arena so when the bucket becomes too old I can drop the whole bucket with its arena.

However, I can't find a way to reason with the lifetime in this situation, if I maintain a `Vec<Arena>` then the lifetime of the objects in the `Vec` is not the same. For my use case I cannot use an `Id` arena because I want to use the objects as keys for a hashmap. I don't want to generate an `Rc` for each item in the arena because that will increase the memory footprint of every item (these are many many very small items), so I want to hold in my bucket actual references to objects allocated in the arena.

Sorry the question is a bit vague but would love some hints on how to address this situation.

Comment: Could you use simple vectors as arenas, and use indices as references?

Comment: `Rc` are _very_ fast. I doubt that using them would have a significant impact on performance, so I'd say use them unless and until _measurements show_ that they cause issues in your specific case.

Comment: Yes I tried with rc first, actually I was inaccurate the real issue is the rc memory footprint, I have many many very small vectors of single bytes, the rc itself is bigger than the vector

Comment: As I mentioned I can't use indices cause I want the "objects" coming from the arena to be used as hashmap keys